# How to assign captions for two tables in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, floats, pdftex, captions

I want to put two tables side by side and my I have included a sample code below. How can we put separate captions for two tables in LaTeX included in one tabular environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
\cline{1-3}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{1-3}
C & B & A \\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
D & E & F \\
\cline{1-3}
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\cline{1-3}
F & E & D \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `tabularx` for outer table and use `table` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CC}
\caption{The first table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    A & B & C \\
    \cline{1-3}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \cline{1-3}
    C & B & A \\
    \end{tabular}
&
\caption{The second table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    D & E & F \\
    \cline{1-3}
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    \cline{1-3}
    F & E & D \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
in cases, when one table is wider than other and wider than the column width, you can manually accommodate columns width of the outer table. for this is more appropriate to use `tabular*` than `tabularx` table environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table*} 
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{C{\dimexpr0.3\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                             C{\dimexpr0.7\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\caption{The first table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    C & B & A \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
&
\caption{The second table}
    \begin{tabular}{*{14}{c}}
    \hline
    D & E & F & G & H & I & J & D & E & F & G & H & I & J   \\
    \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 0   \\
    J & I & H & G & F & E & D & J & I & H & G & F & E & D   \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: This is very good but the problem what happens when Table I has a lot more columns than Table II. How do handle the space and I want these two tables to be placed at the top of a two-column article using `\begin{table*}`

Comment: @Brown, see addendum to answer.

Comment: You are awesome and thank you so much. I have marked your answer as ACCEPTED!

Comment: @Brown, you are welcome!

Comment: One last question. How do we make the table caption have the same width as the Table? I tried something like this `\usepackage[width=.75\textwidth]{caption}`but that affects for other tables and figures which is not something i wanted.

Comment: @Brown, with use of `threeparttable` is easy. but this in longer caption and narrow table can break caption into many lines.

Answer (score 2):

With `minipages` and `captionof` you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
\cline{1-3}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{1-3}
C & B & A \\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{My first caption}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
D & E & F \\
\cline{1-3}
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\cline{1-3}
F & E & D \\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{My second caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
\floatsetup{captionskip=2pt}
\begin{floatrow}
\ttabbox[1.4\FBwidth]{\caption{A First Table}}{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
\cline{1-3}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{1-3}
C & B & A \\
\end{tabular}}

\ttabbox[1.4\FBwidth]{\caption{A Second Table}}{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
D & E & F \\
\cline{1-3}
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\cline{1-3}
F & E & D \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error `Package floatrow Error: Do not use float package with floatrow.`

Comment: Yes, because `floatrow ` redefines the `H` specifier for its own sake, and a few other things. So if you load `float` for ‘H’, you can use it with only `floatrow`.

Comment: It means there is no way to get around this. But thank you!